# Salesforce Sandbox to DocuSign Demo Can't see imported DocuSign templates

Tags: templates, salesforce, docusigncompositetmplts, docusignconnect

I set  up DocuSign-Demo (DSD) and imported my production templates into DSD.
I then set up Salesforce-Sandbox (SFS) and hooked it up tp my DSD.
I do not see my imported templates in my SFS BUT I can create a new template in my SFS and see the new template in DSD right along side of the imported templates from DocuSign-Production.

What am I missing?
Why can I not see all the templates in my DocuSign-Demo from the Salesforce-Sandbox?
I only see the one I created from the SFS on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that Tempalates can cross between Production Environments. I've always had to recreate the Template I made in the Sandbox all over again in Production. I have asked DocuSign Support the same question and am waiting on an answer.